# Passing a vector of object pointers to a class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, containers

I have a vector of Object pointers.

```
std::vector<myObject *> listofObjects;
```

And I want to pass them to another object that needs access to them.

When I try to do something like the following:

```
class NeedsObjects 
{
 public:
    NeedsObjects(std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects)
 private:
    std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects;
};
```

And then initialize the vector in the initialization list I get the following errors:

```
'myObject' was not declared in this scope
template argument 1 is invalid
template argument 2 is invalid
```

What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is pass a vector to the NeedsObjects class.

Comment: You need to declare `myObject` before `NeedsObjects`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the pointers to that object, so you don't have to define the complete object structure, just simply declare it in this file before using it:

```
class myObject; // pre declaration, no need to know the size of the class
class NeedsObjects 
{
 public:
    NeedsObjects(std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects)
 private:
    std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects;
};
```

Comment: @WernerHenze  It is a container of pointers. Surely an incomplete type is allowed here.

Comment: @WernerHenze right, you have to wait until OP makes an edit, then you can remove it :)

Comment: That totally fixed my Problem thank you so much <3

Comment: Now you can give me one more upvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell the compiler what `myObject` is, so it does not know how to create the `std::vector`. Add a reference using an `.h`-file or define `myObject` in this translation-unit.

Either do

```
#include "myObject.h"

class NeedsObjects 
{
 public:
    NeedsObjects(std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects)
 private:
    std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects;
};
```

if you have defined `myObject` in a separate header

or

```
class myObject {
//declaration goes here
};

class NeedsObjects 
{
 public:
    NeedsObjects(std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects)
 private:
    std::vector<myObject *> &listofObjects;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As I see you don't have ANY declaration of myOpbject type visible in your code.

You have basically 2 options:

a) Include header that fully declares myObject.

```
#include "myObject.h" // ... or something near to this.
```

b) Let's think myObject is class. Code you provided here (at least declaration part) doesn't need actually to know myObject size so you can just declare myObject is class and it is declared somewhere else.

```
class myObject;
```

Comment: Adding the header file didn't work, but the partial declaration worked!

Comment: In which header did you declare myObject class?